# How to reset value of state in a Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux-persist

I use **redux-persist** to save my state in local storge, I need after 5-minute finish to log out a user and move a user to a login page, but I can't remove persist value from local storge, every time I try to remove value using **storage.removeItem** the redux-persist return the value back.

RootReducer:

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
    const appReducer  =  combineReducers({
      auth: authReducer,
      //....
    });
    const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
      if (action.type === SIGNOUT_REQUEST) {
        Object.keys(state).forEach(key => {
          storage.removeItem(`persist:${key}`);
      });
        state = undefined;
    }
    return appReducer(state, action);
    }
    export default rootReducer;
```

Logout Action:

```
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: SIGNOUT_REQUEST
  })
```

APP.js

```
if (isTimeout) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
  }
```

index.js

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: if you are sending a sign out action which should make the user unauthed from the app, why does it matter?  Redux-persist will just save that they are no authed.

Comment: I save the auth info in redux-persist so after return the value of auth to default in log out, Redux-persist returns the value of auth again.

Comment: Is the login page an external page not in your app? Or if it is in your app: are you using something like react-router to navigate to it? Or are you forcing a refresh.

Comment: you should re-think saving auth information in `localStorage` https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: @SamVK  My login page in my app.js and I don't use react-router, I just using refresh page.

Comment: @EricHasselbring thanks for your advice :) so what best Storage Engines I can use with redux-persist for sensitive data like user token.

Comment: @MohammadTofi Then that's your real issue. You need to use `react-router`or some sort of app routing so your app behaves like a Single Page App. Currently, your app thinks your user is repeatedly leaving, when they're really just navigating around the site. And your persistor - which usually has time to update state itself - is getting blocked anytime your user switched pages and triggers a refresh. So this will be a recurring problem with any state in your redux store should the user navigate elsewhere before your persistor has time to sync.

Answer (score 4):

You can explicity call [`persistor.flush()`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#persistor-object) after the dispatch to tell the reducer to immediately save the latest state if necessary.

```
import { persistor } from 'store'; // or w/e
// ...
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
      type: SIGNOUT_REQUEST
  });
  persistor.flush();
}
```

---

From [the developer](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/599#issuecomment-348858676):

> `flush` is designed to force the writing of all pending state asap, and to provide a promise to wait for the writes resolution. This can be handy for example if you need to ensure latest state is written before navigating away.

Comment: With that said: presisted state should save automatically after a moment, so if the logout page in in your app, this problem shouldn't happen (assuming you're correctly navigating to the page with something like `react-router` so a browser page refresh isn't triggers. With _that_ said: I think regardless there's an argument for never letting your persistor be out of sync with if you're logged on so this is fine regardless.

Comment: You also probably don't want to be setting state to `undefined`. You likely want to set it to your `initialState` if applicable, or at least an empty object.

Answer (score 3):

To "reset" your entire redux-persist store use `purge()`

```
persistor.purge()
```

> "`purge()` method only clear the content of the storage, leaving the internal data of redux untouched"

> `flush()` as suggested previously is wrong and only flushes pending states: "flush() method for flushing all pending state serialization and immediately write to disk"

https://nicedoc.io/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/api.md