# How to differentiate cart based on user login

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, mern

Hello i have a beginner E-commerce project made using MERN Stack and redux-toolkit as state management and redux-persist, this is my second project so im a beginner. So the problem is when i'm trying to add the product to cart as `user1` the data is updating in the product state and product models in database (it's working), but when i logout as `user1` and logged in as `user2`, when i go to my cart page i still see the product that `user1` add to cart because in the redux state the product is still in the state(i use redux persist, so the data still there when the page is reloaded).

How to differentiate cart based who's user is logged in so when i open the cart page i only see the current cart of my product. And i have a question, when you use data from database do you still update/use the state in redux or do you use the data directly from database and do you need to use redux-persist?. I need an explanation and answer please. Thanks in advance.

Cart Redux :

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    products: [],
  };
  
  const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      addProduct: (state, action) => {
        state.products.push(action.payload);
      },
      removeItem: (state, action) => {
        const index = state.products.findIndex((item) => item._id === action.payload);
        console.log(state.products);
        if (index !== -1) {
          state.products.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  

  export const cartProductsSelector = state => state.cart.products;
  export const cartQuantitySelector = state => state.cart.products.length;
  export const cartTotalSelector = state => state.cart.products.reduce(
    (total, { price = 0, quantity = 1 }) => total + quantity * price,
    0,
  );

  export const { addProduct, removeItem } = cartSlice.actions
  export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

User Redux :

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
       currentUser: null,
       isFetching: false,
       error: false
    },
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.currentUser = null
        }
    }
})

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure, logout } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Store :

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import cartReducer from './cartRedux'
import userReducer from './userRedux'
import {
    persistStore,
    persistReducer,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER,
  } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer, cart: cartReducer });

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

  
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Api Calls :

```
import { loginFailure, loginStart, loginSuccess } from "./userRedux"
import { publicRequest, userMethod } from '../useFetch';
import { addProduct, removeItem } from "./cartRedux";
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const login = async (dispatch, user) => {
    dispatch(loginStart());
    try {
        const res = await publicRequest.post("/login", user);
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch(loginFailure());
    }
}

export const addToCart = async (dispatch, product, quantity, user) => {
    try {
        const res = await userMethod.post("/cart/create", {
            userId: product.user,
            products: product,
            bill: product.quantity * product.price
        });
        dispatch(addProduct({ ...product }));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

export const removeCartItem = createAsyncThunk(
    "cart/removeItem",
    async (cartId, thunkAPI) => {
      try {
        const res = await userMethod.delete(`/cart/delete/${cartId}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
      }
    }
  );
```

Product Page :

```
const Product = () => {

  const [ isSmallerThan704 ] = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 704px)', {
    ssr: true,
    fallback: false, 
  })

  const location = useLocation();
  const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [ product, setProduct ] = useState({});
  const [ quantity, setQuantity ] = useState(1);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser._id);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get("/product/find/"+id);
        setProduct(res.data);
      } catch(err) {
        
      }
    }
    getProduct();
  }, [id])


  const handleClick = () => {
    //update cart
    addToCart(dispatch, ({ ...product, quantity, user }))
  }


  const increment = () => {
    setQuantity(quantity + 1)
  }

  const decrement = () => {
    quantity > 1 && setQuantity(quantity - 1)
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Navbar />
        <Wrapper>
            <ImageContainer>
              <Image src={product.img} alt="product" />
            </ImageContainer>
          <InfoContainer>
            <Title>{product.title}</Title>
            <Desc>
             {product.desc}
            </Desc>
            <Price>$ {product.price}</Price>
          <Flex margin="10px 0 0 5px" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center"  mt="30px">
            <Flex>
              <AiOutlineMinus onClick={decrement} cursor="pointer" />
              <Amount>{quantity}</Amount>
              <GrAdd onClick={increment} cursor="pointer" />
            </Flex>
          
            <Flex>
              <Button padding="15px" border="2px solid teal" backgroundColor="white" cursor="pointer" fontWeight="500" _hover={{backgroundColor : "#f8f4f4"}} 
              onClick={handleClick}>Add to Cart</Button>
            </Flex>
          
            </Flex>
          </InfoContainer>
        </Wrapper>
      <Newsletter />
      <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Product
```

Cart Page :

```
const Cart = () => {

    const cart = useSelector(state=>state.cart);
   
    const [ stripeToken, setStripeToken ] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const onToken = (token) => {
        setStripeToken(token);
    }

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser._id);


    const [ Carts, setCarts ] = useState([]);

    const cartProducts = useSelector(cartProductsSelector);
    const cartQuantity = useSelector(cartQuantitySelector);
    const cartTotal = useSelector(cartTotalSelector);


    useEffect(() => {
        const makeRequest = async () => {
            try{
                const response = await userMethod.post("/checkout/payment", {
                    tokenId: stripeToken.id,
                    amount: 500,
                })
                navigate("/success", { state: {stripeData: response.data, products: cart} });
            } catch (err) {
            } 
        }
        stripeToken &&  makeRequest();
    }, [stripeToken, cart.total, navigate])

    useEffect(() => {
        const makeCartRequest = async () => {
            try{
                const response = await userMethod.get(`/cart/find/${user}`)
                setCarts(response.data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } 
        }
        makeCartRequest();
    }, [user])

    
    const deleteCart = async (cartId, itemId) => {
        try {
          // Asynchronous call to backend, wait to resolve
          await dispatch(removeCartItem(cartId)).unwrap;
    
          // Now dispatch action to remove item from state
          dispatch(removeItem(itemId));
          window.location.reload();
        } catch(error) {
          // handle any errors
          console.log(error);
        }
    };

      console.log(Product)

  return (
    <Container>
        <Navbar />
        <Wrapper>
            <Title>Your Bag</Title>
            <Top>
                <TopButton onClick={deleteCart}>Continue Shopping</TopButton>
                <TopTexts>
                    <TopText>Shooping Bag({cart.quantity})</TopText>
                    <TopText>Your Wishlist</TopText>
                </TopTexts>
                <TopButton type="filled">Checkout Now</TopButton>
            </Top>
            <Bottom>
                <Info>
                {Carts.map((product) => (
                    <>
                    { user === product.userId ? 
                    <Product>
                        <ProductDetail>
                            <Image src={product.products[0].img} alt="google"></Image>
                            <Details>
                                <ProductName><b>Product:</b> {product.products[0].title}</ProductName>
                                <ProductId><b>ID:</b> {product.products[0]._id}</ProductId>
                                <Button onClick={() => {
                                    deleteCart(product._id, product.products[0]._id)
                                }}>Delete</Button>
                            </Details>
                        </ProductDetail>
                        <PriceDetail>
                            <ProductAmountContainer>
                                <AiOutlineMinus />
                                <ProductAmount>{product.products[0].quantity}</ProductAmount>
                                <GrAdd />
                            </ProductAmountContainer>
                            <ProductPrice>$ {product.products[0].price * product.products[0].quantity}</ProductPrice>
                        </PriceDetail>
                    </Product>
                    :
                    null
                    }
                    </>
                    ))}
                    <Hr></Hr>
                </Info>
                <Summary>
                    <SummaryTitle>Order Summary</SummaryTitle>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Subtotal</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ {cartQuantity}</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Estimated Shipping</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ 5</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Shipping Discount</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ -6</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText type="total">Total</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ {cartTotal}</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <StripeCheckout 
                            name="Kimia shop" 
                            image="https://d3o2e4jr3mxnm3.cloudfront.net/Mens-Jake-Guitar-Vintage-Crusher-Tee_68382_1_lg.png"
                            billingAddress
                            shippingAddress
                            description={`your total is $ ${cartTotal}`}
                            amount={cartTotal * 100}
                            token={onToken}
                            stripeKey={KEY}
                            >
                            <Button>Checkout Now</Button>
                        </StripeCheckout>
                </Summary>
            </Bottom>
        </Wrapper>
        <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296953/how-to-reset-value-of-state-in-a-redux-store